# Query Mongo Document as per the latest time stamp from Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

My Mongo collection Nee2500AS1 is having 2 rows:

> db.Nee2500AS1.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ce3ff4c56df46f9defca62"), "asset" : "Nee2500AS1", "SaltRejection" : "82%", "SaltPassage" : "18%", "Recovery" : "56.33%"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ce4013c56df46f9defca63"), "asset" : "Nee2500AS1", "SaltRejection" : "182%", "SaltPassage" : "18%", "Recovery" : "56.33%"}
```

is it possible to query `db.Nee2500AS1.find("Latest Timestamp")`

_id contains time stamp right?

My java code is:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("TESTDoc");
DBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("Nee2500AS1");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(allQuery);
```

How can i modify my java code to fetch latest added row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was simple..

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("Nee2500AS1");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(allQuery).sort( new BasicDBObject( "_id" , -1 ));
DBObject resultElement = null;
resultElement = cursor.next();
```

Here .sort( new BasicDBObject( "_id" , 0 ) returns me the desired result.

Comment: You should use a one or minus one instead of a zero.  Use `new BasicDBObject( "_id" , -1 )` if you want to sort descending (most recent first) or `new BasicDBObject( "_id" , 1 )` to sort ascending (oldest first).

Comment: oh Thanks Trisha.. ill edit my answer .. but when i tried with ("_id" , 0), it gave the descending order as well..

Comment: That's probably a side-effect, and not something you want to rely on, but useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) see [DBCursor javadoc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html).

If you are sorting by something other than the _id you may want to add an index for performance purposes.

```
collection.find(allQuery).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1)).limit(1);
```